# Async/await with FileReader issue

Tags: javascript, async-await, filereader

I have this code to read an Excel sheet into an array of objects. Everything seems to work fine except that readed.onload is performed only when I try to access the data that are not yet loaded (i.e., I suspect that reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file) did not have the time to fire the .onload event, am I right?). Then data are correctly loaded but the program stops at the end of loadFile(file) (i.e., after the resolve statement) seemingly because the call stack is empty.

To be complete, loadFile(file) is called by launchAll() which was called by a .onclick event.

I searched for similar but none reported such a program stop.

I cannot figure out what is going on!

```js
function launchAll() {
      var files = document.getElementById('file_upload').files;
      if (files.length == 0) {
        alert("Please choose any file...");
        return;
      }
      
      loadFile(files[0]
      createEmptyTree()  // Creates forefather and foremother
      createTree()       // Creates DAGs using mappedData (a global variable)
    }

async function loadFile(file) {
    try {
        let fileLoaded = await readFileAsync(file)
        console.log("File loaded !!", fileLoaded)
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error during loading ", err)
    }
};

function readFileAsync(file) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let reader = new FileReader()
        reader.onload = (event) => {
            var data = event.target.result;
            var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
                type: 'binary'
            });
            var roa = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]]);
            if (roa.length > 0) {
                for (i = 0; i < roa.length; i++) {
                    mappedData.push(mapNode(roa[i], i))
                }
            }
            resolve(event)
        }
        reader.onerror = (error) => {
            reject(error)
        };
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file)
    })
}
```

Comment: Do you await `loadFile()`? And: don't use `var` only `let` and always `const` when possible.

Comment: What do you mean by "*when I try to access the data that are not yet loaded*"?

Comment: Please post the code of `launchAll`.

Comment: What is `mappedData`? Where does it come from? Why are you not doing anything with it after pushing data to it? Why do you resolve the promise with the raw `event`, not with the parsed worksheet document?

Comment: @Bergi mappedData is a global structure that captures the data for each line of the XLSX file. It will be used later to create a DAG. Therefore I don't need to resolve with the event.target.result. I did it before and the issue was unchanged.

Comment: @Bergi When createTree() accesses mappedData[0] on its very first line (which is "undefined" because data were not loaded and pushed on it), the program jumps to "reader.onload" and then correctly loads the data. Then it hangs after the resolve statement and I see the call stack is empty. No error message, nothing! I should go back to the line that fired the error

Comment: "*createTree() accesses mappedData[0] on its very first line, which is "undefined" because data were not loaded and pushed on it*" - well that's exactly the problem. You are calling `createEmptyTree(); createTree()` before the data was loaded, because you didn't wait for `loadFile(…)` to finish. You need to `await` that promise in `launchAll`! Instead of using a global variable, you should have resolved the promise with the mapped data, so it's clear that code wanting to use that data needs to wait for the promise result.

Comment: @Bergi We both agree on the diagnosis but I don't understand the cure. How do you ```await```for ```loadFile(...)``` which already is a ```async function```? Also, I'm confusingly figuring out what you mean about the global variable, and I have to think at it.

Comment: It's an `async function`, which means that when called it *immediately* returns a promise (and then will execute parts of its function body later). You need to `await` that promise, in `launchAll`: `await loadFile(files[0]); createEmptyTree(); createTree()`. Ideally you'd do something like `const mappedData = loadFile(files[0]); return createTree(mappedData, createEmptyTree)`

Comment: @Bergi. This is not possible (as I answered to the same suggestion by Kyle) because "``àwait``` expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules." This is why ```loadFile``` awaits for ```readFileAsync```

Comment: @user8889350 Of course this is possible - you need to mark `launchAll` as `async` as well. Or use `loadFile(files[0]).then(…)` syntax instead. Either way, you must wait before using `mappedData`!

Comment: @Bergi I don't understand the logic for putting an async/await within another async/await (```async LauchAll``` ```await```ing for ```async LoadFile``` ```await``` ing readFileAsync. Anyway, trying to do so yields to a "SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules".
Using ```loadFile(files[0]).then``` works well but the program hangs again never reaching ```createEmptyTree()```.
Moving both ```createEmptyTree()```and ```createTree()```inside ```readFileAsync```works fine but someday I will have to exit this function...

Comment: @Bergi I wrote "works well" but the error when attempting to access mappedData[0] is still there... Feeling lost at sea! Seems that ```await readFileAsync``` just does not wait for anything.

Comment: @Bergi @Kyle You guys got the solution since the beginning but I was unable to figure out since now. Thank you!
```async function launchAll() {
      var files = document.getElementById('file_upload').files;
      await loadFile(files[0])      
      createEmptyTree()  // Creates forefather and foremother nodes ([Ø] and [1])
      createTree()       // Creates DAGs using mappedData (a global variable)
    }```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to await loadFile:

```js
// Add async
async function launchAll() {
    // ...
    // Await loadFile
    await loadFile(files[0])
    createEmptyTree()  // Creates forefather and foremother
    createTree()       // Creates DAGs using mappedData (a global variable)
}
```

Comment: No, because "'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules."

Comment: This was finally the right answer but ```function launchAll() {``` needed to be ```async```. Thank you very much.